# How to schedule more job with the same id

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I want to use the android `JobScheduler` to schedule one or more jobs. The problem is the job id. How can I select a differnt job every time? If I schedule new work with the same id, the old job is removed. I would need something like the `enqueuWork` but you need Api level 26, my min api level is 21. How can I do that? Every work is related to the same job, for example: send mail. It's just one job, but it can have several instances.

Comment: So why you just don't use `jobId++` and `PersistableBundle` as job identifier?

Comment: @StanislavBondar How? Are you suggesting to save the last jobId used in the preferences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `JobScheduler`'s `getAllPendingJobs()` method to find out an available `jobID`. It will return all scheduled pending jobs, while they are pending/running. `JobSchedulerService` removes a job from this list once it has finished/completed.

> **Obs.:** Android doc describes:
>   *"Retrieve all jobs for this package that are pending in the `JobScheduler`."*

I have tested this method (on `Android` M and N) and it also returns the Jobs that are running. The job has removed when it is completed. In **Android Source Code**, [`getAllPendingJobs()`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/job/JobSchedulerService.java#L182) uses `mJobs` (stores all the scheduled jobs) to return a job list. When the Job is [Stopped](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/job/JobSchedulerService.java#L346), it is removed from `mJobs`, and it is not returned in `getAllPendingJobs ()`.

Comment: From docs it seems it returns only pending jobs, not running one

Comment: Thank you, I have analyzed and completed my answer with this point. Do you need some more information?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if JobScheduler has that option but if you are able to change it for another component I would recommend you : [FireBase JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android)

It has this option: `.setReplaceCurrent(false)`

```
FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));
Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
    // the JobService that will be called
    .setService(MyJobService.class)
    // uniquely identifies the job
    .setTag("my-unique-tag")
    // one-off job
    .setRecurring(false)
    // don't persist past a device reboot
    .setLifetime(Lifetime.UNTIL_NEXT_BOOT)
    // start between 0 and 60 seconds from now
    .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0, 60))
    // don't overwrite an existing job with the same tag
    .setReplaceCurrent(false)
    // retry with exponential backoff
    .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
    // constraints that need to be satisfied for the job to run
    .setConstraints(
        // only run on an unmetered network
        Constraint.ON_UNMETERED_NETWORK,
        // only run when the device is charging
        Constraint.DEVICE_CHARGING
    )
    .setExtras(myExtrasBundle)
    .build();

dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
```

I had to use it and it works very well

Comment: I was using it but it has a dependcy with Google Play Services, so I prefer to avoid to use it, since my app has min level 21, I'd like to use only built-in methods.

Comment: @greywolf82 Well if that so I would use a base identifier an adding numbers to that in order to avoid overlapping. Plus I would save those ids in sharedPref or a database.

Comment: Yep, I think the old good shared preferences are the best solution in this case.